# Merge 2 collection with matching id and removing unnecessary data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
public function getCartItemsCount(Request $request) {
  $product_count = Product::whereIn(
      'id', Auth::user()
      ->getCartItems
      ->pluck('product_id'))
      ->get();

  $quantity = Cart::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
  return $quantity->merge($product_count);
}
```

It returns like this:

[
{

```
"id": 1,
"user_id": 11,
"quantity": 1,
"product_id": 9,
"created_at": "2021-06-20T23:11:08.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-06-20T23:11:09.000000Z"
```

},
{

```
"id": 2,
"user_id": 11,
"quantity": 4,
"product_id": 3,
"created_at": "2021-06-20T23:11:15.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-06-20T23:11:16.000000Z"
```

},
{

```
"id": 3,
"name": "Den's Ultimate Overload",
"brand": "Den's Cafe",
"category": "Food",
"sub_category": null,
"price": 374,
"average_rating": 5,
"created_at": "2021-06-23T23:52:54.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-06-23T23:52:55.000000Z"
```

},
{

```
"id": 9,
"name": "French Fries",
"brand": "Jollibee",
"category": "Food",
"sub_category": null,
"price": 35,
"average_rating": 4,
"created_at": "2021-06-23T23:53:00.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-06-23T23:53:01.000000Z"
```

}
]

Objective: the data should be like this

```
[
```

{

```
"id": 3,
"name": "Den's Ultimate Overload",
"quantity:" 4, 
"brand": "Den's Cafe",
"category": "Food",
"sub_category": null,
"price": 374,
"average_rating": 5,
"created_at": "2021-06-23T23:52:54.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-06-23T23:52:55.000000Z"
```

},
{

```
"id": 9,
"name": "French Fries",
"quantity:" 1,
"brand": "Jollibee",
"category": "Food",
"sub_category": null,
"price": 35,
"average_rating": 4,
"created_at": "2021-06-23T23:53:00.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-06-23T23:53:01.000000Z"
```

}
]

Note: the quantity must be assign with the same product id and id

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_replace_recursive method
like,

$combined = array_replace_recursive($quantity, $product_count);

it return values which you want.

/* for an example

```
$color = array(
          array('id' => 1, 'color' => 'red'),
          array('id' => 2, 'color' => 'green'),
          array('id' => 3, 'color' => 'blue')
        );

$size = array(
         array('id' => 1, 'size' => 'SM'),
         array('id' => 2, 'size' => 'XL'),
         array('id' => 3, 'size' => 'MD'),
         array('id' => 4, 'size' => 'LG'),
        );

$merged = array_replace_recursive($color, $size);
var_dump($merged);
exit;

Output of this like:
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [color] => red [size] => SM )
 [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [color] => green [size] => XL )
 [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [color] => blue [size] => MD )
 [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [size] => LG ) 
)
```

*/

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getCartItemsCount(Request $request) {
  $product_count = Product::whereIn('id', Auth::user()->getCartItems->pluck('product_id'))->orderBy('brand', 'asc')->get();
  $quantity = Cart::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();

  foreach($product_count->toBase('product_id')->concat($quantity) as $product) {
      if($product->product_id) {
          $new = $product_count->where('id', $product->product_id)->first();
          $new->quantity = $product->quantity;
      }
  }
  // this return a data wherein it merge with matching the product id and the id. this is use for mergin the data of users added to cart and product details. For ecommerce.
  return $product_count;
}
```

i got the answer after so many trials. Note: you can use pluck method to get data that you need.